# How to solve this irrational equation?

Tags: problem-solving

How to solve this equation in the set real numbers $$\sqrt{8x + 1} - \sqrt{6x - 2} - 2x^2 + 8x - 7 = 0.$$ Using Mathematica, I know, this equation has two solutions $x = 1$ and $x = 3.$

Comment: Guessing solutions is not an option for you or? What is a solution for you? Only a analytical way, or are you interested in numerical solutions too ?

Answer (score 6):

I don't really recommend the following, but a general ansatz for $$\sqrt P - \sqrt Q = R$$ where $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are polynomials in a single unknown, might be to multiply with the conjugate:
$$ P - Q = R\sqrt P + R\sqrt Q$$
then expand using $\sqrt P = R+\sqrt Q$ to get
$$P - Q = R^2 + 2R\sqrt Q $$
and thus
$$ (P - Q - R^2)^2 = 4R^2 Q$$
so the solutions you seek will be roots of some real polynomial -- but some of the roots will be non-solutions, and the final polynomial will generally have inconveniently high degree.

You can always do this and apply the rational root test to see if there are any *nice* solutions to the original equation, though. If not, then you might as well just solve the original numerically.

Answer (score 3):

Write:

$$\sqrt{8x + 1} - \sqrt{6x - 2} - 2x^2 + 8x - 7 = 0.$$

As:

$$(\sqrt{8x + 1} - \sqrt{6x - 2}) = (2x^2 - 8x + 7).$$

Squaring both sides yields:

$$14 x-2 \sqrt{6 x-2}\sqrt{8 x+1}-1 = 4x^4-32x^3+92x^2-112x+49$$

Simplifying:

$$-2 \sqrt{6 x-2}\sqrt{8 x+1} = 4x^4-32x^3+92x^2-112x+49$$

Squaring both sides again yields:

$$ 4(6x-2)(8x+1) = 16 x^8-256 x^7+1760 x^6-6896 x^5+16928 x^4-26384 x^3+25076 x^2-12600 x+2500$$

Simplifying:

$$16 x^8-256 x^7+1760 x^6-6896 x^5+16928 x^4-26384 x^3+24884 x^2-12560 x+2508 = 0$$

This gives us more roots, so care must be taken, but indeed, we get back two of the $8$ roots as $x = 1$ and $x = 3$.

Numerical methods would also have worked earlier and guessing too.

Regards

Comment: @ Amzoti If you don't use your computer, can you solve this way?

Comment: @minthao_2011: I would try guessing, looking for patterns...

Comment: After finding $1$ and $3$ the remaining degree 6 polynomial turns out to be irreducible, so I won't try to compute $0.52485827544931491853347971043769008417$, $1.8557252925237647158115422848991734380$, $2.1338481507510021756733333358175364607$, $4.4517218947934982880461421562125906714$, $1.5169231932412099509677512563165046726\pm 1.8292676510086687936566891455556287623 i$ without computer. Not to mention check (the real numbers) if they fulfil the original equation - which they don't, as it turns out.

Comment: +1, this is slightly slicker than my suggestion -- specifically with respect to how easy it is to convince oneself the whole thing ought not to collapse to $0=0$ when simplifying.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: thank you and I always enjoy reading your answers as they help me learn!

Comment: @amWhy: these can ugly quickly, but the algebra is fun, especially since I can't even add! :-) thx

Answer (score 2):

Note that, with $x=1$, $y=\sqrt{8x+1}$ takes the value $y=3$ and  with $x=3$, $y=\sqrt{8x+1}$ takes the value $y=5$. Put the point $A(1, 3)$ and $B(3,5)$. The equation of the line passing two points $A$ and $B$ is $y = x + 2.$ And then we write $$\sqrt{8x + 1}-(x+2).$$ Similar to with  $$(x+1- \sqrt{6x - 2}).$$
We write the given equation has the form
$$ \sqrt{8x + 1}-(x+2)  + (x+1- \sqrt{6x - 2})  =2(x^2 - 4x + 3). $$
equavalent to $$ \dfrac{-(x^2 -4x + 3)}{ \sqrt{8x + 1}+(x+2)}+ \dfrac{x^2 -4x + 3}{x+1 +  \sqrt{6x - 2}}=2(x^2 - 4x + 3).$$
Or
$$ (x^2 -4x + 3)\left(\dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{8x + 1}+(x+2)}+ 2- \dfrac{1}{x+1 +  \sqrt{6x - 2}}\right)=0.$$
With $x\geqslant \dfrac{1}{3}$, it is easy to see that
$$  \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{8x + 1}+(x+2)}+ 2- \dfrac{1}{x+1 +  \sqrt{6x - 2}} >0.$$
Therefore we get $$  x^2 -4x + 3 = 0.$$

Comment: What is so special about the equation of the secant line that it allowed you to factor so nicely?

Comment: You know for sure that the remaining function after you subtracted the secant term has roots at $1$ and $3$.